# The singular points and residues of $\sin(\frac 1 z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I met a question asking all the singular points and corresponding residues of

$$ \sin \frac 1 z  $$

My understanding is that

$$\sin \frac 1 z=\frac 1 z-\frac 1{3!z^3}+\frac 1 {5!z^5}+... $$

Thus there is only one singular point which is 0 and residue is 1.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps a little elaboration on the "Thus" wouldn't be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Possible singular points are $(0)$
at $z=0, Sin(\frac{1}{0}=\infty)$ So there is a singularity at 0

**Test fot removable singularity**
$$Lim_{z \rightarrow 0}(z-0)sin(\frac{1}{z})= 1 \neq 0$$ So this is not a removable singularity

**Test for a Pole**

It cannot be a pole too Why?(see defn)

Hence it is a essential singularity with residue $1$, Since coeff of $\frac{1}{z}$